# Error running Visual Studio Express 2013 Blink example on Intel Galileo

Tags: visual-studio, intel-galileo

My Intel Galileo board (received via Windows on IoT program, thanks a lot Microsoft) can runs the Arduino sketches directly via IDE downloaded from Intel. However when I try the Blink example from Visual Studio Express 2013, it compiles OK and loads to the Galileo (browsing c:\test shows the .exe file), but the throws following errors:

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\test\GalileoVS Blink.exe'. Symbols loaded.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\embprpusr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mincoredload.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*First-chance exception at 0x77D50F63 in GalileoVS Blink.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _arduino_fatal_error at memory location 0x006FF078.*

*Sketch Aborted! A fatal error has occurred:*
*Failed to configure I2C_CONTROLLER mux*

*First-chance exception at 0x77D50F63 in GalileoVS Blink.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _arduino_fatal_error at memory location 0x006FF4D4.*

*'GalileoVS Blink.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\errorhandlingext.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.*

*Unhandled exception at 0x77D50F63 in GalileoVS Blink.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _arduino_fatal_error at memory location 0x006FF4D4.*

Running directly the executable via telnet gives following error:

*Sketch Aborted! A fatal error has occurred:*

*Failed to configure I2C_CONTROLLER mux*

What might be a problem here - the board itself (why the I2C_CONTROLLER mux failed to configure?), the SD-card Windows image (received in the box with the card), or something is missing in my Visual Studio installation? Any advice and help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on my board.  Could be a number of things.  But I think to start shutdown the galileo and plug the sd card in the computer and reload the windows image after you saved your test programs. Sometimes if you shut power off immediately without shutting down the galileo through software, shutdown /s in cmd prompt the sd card gets corrupted. Sometimes the Nuget package nukes the configuration settings inside visual studio.  Stack Overflow has an explanation on this, can't remember the fix for that but, I suggest reloading the nuget package with an up to date version.  Copying your cpp files h files into a new folder, making a new project and copying the data back in.  Hopefully that works, curious how you got this working.  Good Luck.